# I want to generate marksheet containing percentage, rank standard wise and division wise in oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, analytic-functions

Here is my column

```
create table exam_details(
         Stud_id varchar2(50),
         Stud_course_id Number,
         Stud_div char,
         Stud_Sub_id Number,
         Stud_Marks Number,
         Sub_total_Marks Number,
         Exam_id Number,
         Exam_date Date
         );
```

and content for db is

```
        insert into exam_details values ('1A1',1,'A',1,55,100,1,'2-jan-2015');
         insert into exam_details values ('1A1',1,'A',2,65,100,1,'3-jan-2015');
        insert into exam_details values ('1A1',1,'A',3,72,100,1,'5-jan-2015');


         insert into exam_details values ('1B1',1,'B',1,45,100,1,'2-jan-2015');
          insert into exam_details values ('1B1',1,'B',2,65,100,1,'3-jan-2015');
          insert into exam_details values ('1B1',1,'B',3,58,100,1,'5-jan-2015');

         insert into exam_details values ('2A1',2,'A',1,75,100,1,'2-jan-2015');
          insert into exam_details values ('2A1',2,'A',2,65,100,1,'3-jan-2015');
         insert into exam_details values ('2A1',2,'A',3,82,100,1,'5-jan-2015');
```

I have tried But i am getting result only for

```
select stud_id, 
   RANK() OVER(ORDER BY stud_marks DESC) AS "Rank"
from exam_details;
```

Comment: `'2-jan-2015'` is not a `date`, it is a `string` literal. Use `to_date` to convert it into a `date`, else your `insert` statements are of no use.

Comment: thanks,but i have only focus only on division wise markwise and percentage wise mark and i tried on oracle 10g

Comment: If you don't edit your insert statements, nobody would be able to use your test case.

Comment: Oracle will probably do an implicit conversion to DATE for that particular string literal.

Comment: What do you mean by "percentage"?

Comment: And how to generate report from it? which contain percentage of

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this one:

```
select stud_id, Stud_div,
   RANK() OVER(ORDER BY stud_marks DESC) AS Rank_all,
   RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Stud_div ORDER BY stud_marks DESC) AS Rank_div
from exam_details;
```

Comment: I want to generate simple report containing rank and percentage of student